# google app scripts trying to get proper scope in Spotify API OAuth call

Tags: api, google-apps-script, spotify

I have the following function in google app scripts that is supposed to connect with the proper scope to Spotify API. I can connect and do basic API calls, but when trying to get my personal recently played songs, I am seeing the following error.

```
function main() {
  //"scope" : "user-read-recently-played"
  
  var url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";
  var params = {
    method: "post",
    headers: {"Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(oauth.OAUTH_CLIENT_ID + ":" + oauth.OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET),
              "scope" : "user-read-recently-played"},
    payload: {grant_type: "client_credentials"},
  };
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  Logger.log(res.getContentText());

  var obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  accToken = obj.access_token;
  Logger.log(accToken);

  // searchSpotify();

  getRecentlyPlayed();
}
```

Error:

> Exception: Request failed for https://api.spotify.com returned code
> 403. Truncated server response: {   "error" : {
> "status" : 403,
> "message" : "Insufficient client scope"   }

I know my client id and secret work correctly as I can make basic searches through the API. I am trying to make a restful call to:

> url:
> https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/recently-played?limit=10&after=1643483216932

Any ideas how I can connect, get a validly scoped token to use for lookups? Thank you for any help!

phi

Comment: what's in `obj.scope`?

Comment: This is all that is in obj = {token_type=Bearer, expires_in=3600.0, access_token=BQDvat*********************YyHnZdR_o}

obj.scope = null

Comment: I'm probably just not putting the scope arg in the right place, I just haven't found documentation anywhere to tell me how to send it in this case.

Comment: Notice https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/client-credentials/ says > Since this flow does not include authorization, only endpoints that do not access user information can be accessed. I thinks you out of luck

Comment: To get user information you need to use this flow: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/ For Apps Script use this lib: https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2 use [this example](https://gist.github.com/Bajena/9750298dbe848651f0bc8a2e10b400a1)

Comment: This is excellent information @kos Thank you so much!